# sendmail: error while loading shared libraries. libmysqlclient.so.18 cannot open shared object file no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to run script in Linux uat server which is for to send a mail. we are using redhat 7 version.
It runs fine on testing server but not in uat.
and this error is coming
`sendmail: error while loading shared libraries. libmysqlclient.so.18. cannot open shared object file. no such file or directory`

I'm pretty new to scripting and Linux. can anyone help me on this what it means

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing library

```
yum install mariadb-libs
```